# Log4j logs decreases application performance?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Does logging decreases application performance?
and how to restrict display-tags logs to be printed in log files?

eg. my log file has below logs

```
[2012-06-20 15:52:06,290] org.displaytag.tags.TableTag isFirstIteration 684 - [data] first iteration=true (row number=1)
[2012-06-20 15:52:06,290] org.displaytag.tags.TableTag isFirstIteration 684 - [data] first iteration=true (row number=1)
[2012-06-20 15:52:06,290] org.displaytag.tags.TableTag isFirstIteration 684 - [data] first iteration=true (row number=1)
[2012-06-20 15:52:06,290] org.displaytag.tags.TableTag isFirstIteration 684 - [data] first iteration=true (row number=1)
```

why the above is in log file?

log.properties file

```
# Log4j configuration file.
 log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, A1
 # Available levels are DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL

 #
 # A1 is a ConsoleAppender 
 #

log4j.appender.A1 = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File = C:/LogInfo/logfile.log
log4j.appender.A1.MaxFileSize = 100MB
log4j.appender.A1.MaxBackupIndex=50
log4j.appender.A1.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.append = true
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern = [%d] %C %M %L - %m%n
log4j.appender.A1.Threshold = DEBUG
```

how to stop (org.displaytag.tags.TableTag) these kind of logs to be printed in log files

Comment: possible duplicate of [log4j performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053134/log4j-performance)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Does logging decreases application performance?

Yes.  How much it does depends on a number of factors; see below.

> and how to restrict display-tags logs to be printed in log files?

By changing the ConversionPattern in the logging properties

> why the above is in log file?

Because:

1. somewhere in the code is a call to a Logger method (probably `debug(String)`) with that message, and
2. your logging properties set the logging Threshold to DEBUG for the appender.

To improve performance:

1. change the ConversionPattern to use less expensive date/time formatting, and (more importantly) avoid 'C', 'F', 'L' and 'M' because they are particularly expensive.
2. change the logging Threshold to INFO or WARNING or ERROR to reduce the amount of logging,
3. put the `Logger.debug(...)` call inside an `if` statement that checks that debug logging is enabled.  This saves the cost of assembling the log message in cases where it won't be needed; see [In log4j, does checking isDebugEnabled before logging improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963492/in-log4j-does-checking-isdebugenabled-before-logging-improve-performance).
4. with log4j version 2 (log4j2), there are overloads that on the logging methods that take a format and parameters.  These reduce the overhead when a logging at a level that is disabled.
5. look also at logback and log4j 2.0.

You can also throttle logging at the `Logger` level ... as described in the [log4j documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).  In fact, the documentation answers most of the questions that you asked, and has a lot of detail on the topics of logging performance and logging configuration.

Comment: if I use INFO then will I get logs like(logger.debug(...)) in my log file?

Comment: @happy - read the manual ... see link in my Answer. It is all explained there.  (The answer is "no".)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: yes, it decreases application performance as it uses some CPU cycles and other resources (memory, etc).

See also this question : [log4j performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053134/log4j-performance)

Answer (score 1):

Logging can be 30% of you cpu time or more. In terms of jitter, it as large (and more often) than your GC delays.

A simple way to reduce overhead is to use the Pattern to turn off where you are logging each message from. In your case this is %C %M and %L as it has to take a stack trace (of the entier stack) to get this information.

Comment: how to use Pattern to turn off?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they do. That's why you should only log an error or something that must absolutely be logged. You can also log information helpful for debugging in the debug channel so it won't affect production performance.

Comment: how to stop (org.displaytag.tags.TableTag) these kind of logs to be printed in log files

Comment: @happy take them out of your conversion pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict junk logs like this.
Set the root logger as INFO so that unnecessary debug logs won't come and fill up your log file.

```
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, A1
```

If you want specific class or package to give out DEBUG logs you can do it like this.

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener=DEBUG,A1
```

The above will print DEBUG level logs from the class DefaultLoadEventListener in your log file along with other INFO level logs.

Comment: if I use INFO then will I get logs like(logging.debug(...)) in my log file?

Comment: No only logging.info(...) logs will come.For testing or debugging you should use the DEBUG level , for deployment it should be INFO.If you want you can specifically enable DEBUG logs for certain class  as i have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

how about?

```
log4j.category.org.displaytag.tags.TableTag=ERROR, A1
```