# Multiple appenders log4j performance

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j

I am using slf4j, implementation of log4j for logging in my java project. Currently I am having 2 appenders, FILE and CONSOLE.

I want to know following 2 things:

- Does using multiple appenders (in this case CONSOLE and FILE) causes performance issue in logging?
- When somebody would want to use CONSOLE and FILE appenders both?

Comment: 1. No  2. When you want to see the logging output on screen , but could be that some of the vital info scrolled , so you can always look into the log file for further debugging

Comment: Why there is no performance change? Can you throw some insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing to CONSOLE and FILE, you are writing to 2 different streams. In a multithreaded system, the performance hit will not be much, but with big volumes it is still apparent.

From the [log4J manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

```
The typical cost of actually logging is about 100 to 300 microseconds.
```

This includes building the statement and writing it, but the time taken for writing will still be apparent if you are logging heavily.

But you need to ask a more basic question - **Why are you logging?**

1. to keep track of what is going on
2. to find out errors

The CONSOLE is not useful for the first part as the logs are not saved anywhere. If the logging is heavy, and all the logs are sent to the CONSOLE, the amount of logs will make the output on the console unreadable, so purpose 2 is also defeated.

IMO it makes much more sense reading logs from a file using something like *less*. As a general practice, you log to file and if you must, log only the ERROR messages to console, as a few ERROR messages would be an indicator of something going wrong, whereas hundreds of log lines on console is just junk, as you cannot make any sense of it when the console is refreshing so rapidly.

**TL-DR**

*The cost might not be much, but why incur an added cost when you are getting no added advantage?*

Read these links on log 4j performance.
[log4j-performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053134/log4j-performance)
[log4j-decreased application performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117916/log4j-logs-decreases-application-performance)
[log4j appenders](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html)

Answer (score -1):

1. I challenge you to notice any performance change.
2. For instance you might want a daemon application to log both in the console and in a file. It does not seem to be such an uncommon behavior.

Comment: Why there is no performance change? Can you throw some insight?

Comment: accept the answer first please. will shade the light on perf change :)